# Should I call XMLHttpRequest async within promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, xmlhttprequest

I use a basic `XMLHttpRequest` within a `promise`. Due to the async nature of the `promise`, I always assumed that having the `XMLHttpRequest` sync is fine, but since my browser is warning me about it I wanted to make sure.

A `mwe` would be:

```
call(arg) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080?' + arg.name, false);
        xhr.send();
        resolve({body: {result: xhr.responseText}});
    });
}
```

Comment: No, it’s not fine. Outside of some specific tools, JavaScript is single-threaded, and you will be causing the UI to hang as usual in a promise if you use synchronous XHR, same as if you did it in an event listener, `setTimeout` callback, ….

Comment: Side note: If you want promise-enabled ajax, just use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I call XMLHttpRequest async within promise?

Yes, asynchronous (not synchronous).

> Due to the async nature of the promise, I always assumed that having the `XMLHttpRequest` sync is fine...

It isn't, for a couple of reasons:

1. *Asynchronous* is not the same as *on another thread*. You're still blocking the main UI thread.
2. The promise executor function (the function you pass to `new Promise`) is executed *synchronously* anyway. So your `call` won't return until the ajax call is complete, because it's a synchronous call.

Promises don't change the nature of the work being done. They just provide consistent, standardized syntax for observing the result of work being done (usually asynchronous work, but it doesn't have to be).

The only thing promises make asynchronous is calls to `then`, `catch`, and `finally` handlers. See the comments and results in this snippet for details:

```js
// The promise executor is called *synchronously*.
// This outputs 1, 2, 3, not 1, 3, 2:
console.log(1);
new Promise(resolve => {
  console.log(2);
  resolve();
});
console.log(3);

// `then`, `catch`, and `inally` handlers are called asynchronously, even if
// the promise is already settled (because it would be chaotic to call them
// synchronously *sometimes* [because the promise is already settled when you
// call `then`/`catch/`finally`] but not *other* times [because it isn't
// settled yet when you call `then`/`catch/`finally`]).
// This outputs A, B, C, not A, C, B
console.log("A");
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log("C"));
console.log("B");
```

Don't do synchronous ajax, there's just no good reason to in 2019.

---

Side note: If you want promise-enabled ajax, use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch).

Comment: OK, this makes sense, I'll do that then. I'll try to figure out the `fetch` part. As I have to return a promise I can feed an API.

Comment: @magu_ - `fetch` returns a promise. You'll probably want to wrap it, though as the raw `fetch` API has [a surprising "feature"](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) *(that's a link to a post about it on my anemic little blog)*. `XMLHttpRequest` also isn't going away anytime soon, so you can just change your `false` to `true` and not worry about `fetch` for now. Happy coding!

Comment: That's what I will be ending up doing since I need to play a bit with the formatting of the response. Thanks for your quick help.